# Angular CLI ng new error EEXIST: file already exists Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

I have been trying to create an angular project on Windows 10 with the ng new command for days now. 
The same log error seems to keep occurring as below.

```
   OS: Windows 10 pro x64
   NPM Version: 6.14.4
   NodeJS Version: v12.16.2
   Angular CLI: 9.1.1
   Node: 12.16.2
   OS: win32 x64
```

**Angular Ivy Workspace:**

```
Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.901.1

@angular-devkit/core         9.1.1

@angular-devkit/schematics   9.1.1

@schematics/angular          9.1.1

@schematics/update           0.901.1

rxjs                         6.5.4
```

**What have I tried:**

1. I have uninstalled and re-installed NodeJS and npm and angular CLI.
2. I have force cleared my npm cache (*npm cache clear --force*)
3. I have verified my npm cache (*npm cache verify*)
4. I have removed all angular installations
5. I have reinstalled angular *npm install -g @angular/cli@latest*

Other Info

- The Angular CLI is installed in C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm
  where @angular is under node_modules.
- My NodeJS is installed in C:\Program Files\nodejs where I have npm under modules but not
  @angular?
- My account has administrator privileges.

**Stuff that seems strange to me:**

When I install using PowerShell @angular/cli with the -g flag, the installation seems to install ONLY in the directory I am in, the @angular does not magically get installed in C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm I had to run the cmd from that directory to get it installed there? Not sure if there is an issue with my environment variables or something?

**Logs after running ng new angular-tut-ws:**

```
33716 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
33717 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: util-deprecate@1.0.2 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\util-deprecate):
33718 warn enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\util-deprecate' -> 'C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.util-deprecate.DELETE'
33719 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
33719 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
33720 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: wrappy@1.0.2 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\wrappy):
33721 warn enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\wrappy' -> 'C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.wrappy.DELETE'
33722 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
33722 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
33723 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: yallist@3.1.1 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\yallist):
33724 warn enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\yallist' -> 'C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.yallist.DELETE'
33725 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
33725 verbose enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
33726 verbose stack Error: EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws\node_modules\browserslist\cli.js' -> 'C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws\browserslist'
33726 verbose stack     at simulateEEXIST (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\bin-link.js:87:15)
33726 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\gentle-fs\lib\bin-link.js:69:21
33726 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-cmd-shim\index.js:52:12
33726 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:115:16
33726 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
33727 verbose cwd C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws
33728 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
33729 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
33730 verbose node v12.16.2
33731 verbose npm  v6.14.4
33732 error code EEXIST
33733 error path C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws\node_modules\browserslist\cli.js
33734 error dest C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws\browserslist
**33735 error EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws\node_modules\browserslist\cli.js' -> 'C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws\browserslist'
33736 error File exists: C:\Users\User\Documents\projects\angular-tut-ws\browserslist**
33737 error Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
33738 error with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
33739 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: So I managed to resolve this, however, I do not know which part was the resolution. I found a few angular files sitting in C:\Users\User where I deleted them and deleted any external folder containing the folder @angular. I reinstalled angular cli in the app data roaming folder and created a new angular project ng new on my desktop and it worked.